# NXT BrickNotFoundError

Tags: ros, nxt, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.4 Lucid on a virtualbox VM and using ROS Electric with the NXT packages. ROS and the NXT packages installed fine and all, but when conducting the initial touch sensor test, I get the error listed in the PostInstall page (which I've copy-pasted below). All the page says regarding the error is "Your computer is not configured correctly or the brick is off if you see [this error]". However the page doesn't mention how to fix said error. The brick is not off, I can plainly see that from looking at it. However, I don't know how to go about trouble shooting it.

The only thing I can think is that my VM isn't registering my USB connection to the brick, but I've successfully installed the virtualbox extensions to allow for USB devices to be recognized and I've tested it using a USB flashdrive. Is there anyway I can look somewhere to see if my Linux VM is even registering that it is connected? I'm going to try updating the firmware of my NXT brick off of my VM to see if that will help anything, but I've looked all over the ROS Answers and the wiki and can't find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
$ rosrun nxt_python touch_sensor_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/nxt_python/sensor_tests/touch_sensor_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    sock = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/nxt_python/src/nxt/locator.py", line 57, in find_one_brick
    raise BrickNotFoundError
nxt.locator.BrickNotFoundError
```

EDIT: I know you can also use bluetooth with the NXT bricks, but I have even less of an idea of how to get that set up with Linux.

I've been trying to see if my brick will register any connections to no avail. I can't even update the firmware or anything. I should also mention that I no longer have the NXT-G software that came with the NXT, so I have no idea how to go about connecting my brick. :S

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37109/nxt-bricknotfounderror/) by [Nezteb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2691/nezteb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. Apparently Lego has a free Mindstorms client to update the Firmware. Unfortunately you need a Mac or PC to do so. I updated the firmware using my Mac (which has my Linux VM within it), and then my computer would finally recognize the device. Then I just needed to go into the virtualbox settings and tell it to allow the unknown device to connect to my linux VM. Now it works like a charm. :)

---

Originally posted by [Nezteb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2691/nezteb/) with karma: 32 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-06-25**:
I don't know if you have enough karma, but you should / could mark your own answer as accepted (as you did solve it). Just to clarify: your brick had a firmware version < 1.28?

**Comment by [Nezteb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2691/nezteb/) on 2012-06-26**:
I don't have enough karma unfortunately. But yes, my brick had firmware version 1.01 and I updated it to 1.31.